# Change calendar view's layout

Tags: jquery, calendar, css

I have a calendar list with about 8 views created by filtering on Location. Is it possible to have these views appear differently than the default? I've selected "Week" as the scope for all the views. Here's what I need:

- The calendar is shaded to indicate the workweek from Monday - Friday, 8 - 5. Can this be changed? So the workweek would be from Sunday - Thursday, 8 - 5:30 p.m.
- Can the full day name appear at the top instead of the one letter abbreviation?
- Can we set the display time range for the days of the week? It currently defaults to 7 a.m. - 7 p.m. for the calendar. We'd like it to go from 6 a.m. to 10 p.m.
- Can the calendar display area be scrollable vertically? This way, we limit its height to a set value and let the user scroll inside.

The calendar is based on a custom content type, which is based on the Event type. I have access to jQuery so if these changes require it, that's no problem. Thank you :)

Comment: can you include SP version you are using? 2007 or 2010?

Comment: Sorry. It's 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your work week and time range by changing your site Regional settings under `Site Settings > Site Administration > Regional Settings > Define Your Work Week`.
By applying different work week and time range your calendar will render differently (maybe not exactly as you require).

To make other desired changes you will need to use jQuery and/or css.

Comment: Thanks, Vedran. I'm using 2010 version. The change you suggested worked like a charm. Also, I found this blog post on changing the colors of the calendar: http://scottcurrier.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/creating-color-coded-entries-within-the-otb-sharepoint-calendar/